# On macOS with Autotools, how to tell libA to find its dependency libB at a custom location instead of compiler defaults?

Tags: macos, build, autotools

I have libA and libB, libA depends on libB. Both use Autotools as the build system.

### Problem

On macOS, libA always try to find libB under `/usr/local/lib`, while the source code structure is like this

- `libA`
- `libB`

i.e., they are side by side under the same parent folder.

### Question

How do I instruct `libA` that `libB` is at the custom location instead of the compiler defaults? Note that libA may depend on other things, which may be system default. Only `libB` is at the custom location.

### Workaround

I do know I could use Homebrew to cheat a bit on dependency hassles. But I'd really love to build from source in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

libA's `./configure` supports custom compiler flags such as `LDFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`. In my case, it even comes with custom flags `libB_CFLAGS` and `libB_LIBS`.

So with those custom flags set, and `./configure LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -lB"`. I'm good to go.